# Chrome kiosk mode is not enabled until fullscreened

Tags: linux, google-chrome, fullscreen, kiosk

I know that Chromium can be started in kiosk mode with the flag --kiosk in the terminal. However, when Chromium is begun, it is in a regular windowed mode. Kiosk mode isn't enabled until the user presses F11 or fullscreens the window another way. How can Chrome automatically be fullscreened and in kiosk mode after the command is executed in the terminal?

Comment: As [some answer on askubuntu suggests](http://askubuntu.com/questions/267916/how-can-i-get-chromium-browser-to-run-fullscreen-not-kiosk-in-12-04), do the following: `chromium-browser --kiosk; sleep 5; xdotool key F11`.

Comment: That won't work, actually. No command after chromium-browser --kiosk is executed.

Comment: Ah, of course! I forgot that you should put `&` after `chromium-browser --kiosk` so it runs on background, and then it should work. You'd also try the actual suggestion of the answer I linked: `chromium-browser --start-maximized &; sleep 5; xdotool key F11`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to programmatically press <kbd>F11</kbd>, and that's possible with [`xdotool`](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool): it can emulate key-presses and do many other things too.

The solution is to create a shell script (or just one-liner), which runs chromium in background, sleeps a few seconds and then virtually presses <kbd>F11</kbd>:

```
chromium-browser --kiosk & sleep 5; xdotool key F11
```

That can also be done as a multi-liner (save this, for example, as `chromium-kiosk.sh`):

```
chromium-browser --kiosk &
sleep 5
xdotool key F11
```

#### Reference

- [Askubuntu question titled How can I get chromium-browser to run fullscreen (not kiosk) in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/267916/how-can-i-get-chromium-browser-to-run-fullscreen-not-kiosk-in-12-04)

Comment: `chromium-browser -kiosk --start-fullscreen`